# how to remove \\' from a string in Python2.7

Tags: python

how to remove \' from a string in Python2.7,
i got a string from server:

```
'(\\'1\\',\\'YoTWsmjxk4M5lqgmzKzF8oI6owoqJBM5mVumQ-0fL01OLS9gU63Gfw**\\',\\'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x94\\xa7\\x2f\\x34\\',\\'\\',\\'2\\');'
```

and how to transfer to

```
'('1','YoTWsmjxk4M5lqgmzKzF8oI6owoqJBM5mVumQ-0fL01OLS9gU63Gfw**','\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x94\\xa7\\x2f\\x34','','2')'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your string looks like double quoted. Please give more context in how you got it and how you extracted it from Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "'(\\'1\\',\\'YoTWsmjxk4M5lqgmzKzF8oI6owoqJBM5mVumQ-0fL01OLS9gU63Gfw**\\',\\'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x94\\xa7\\x2f\\x34\\',\\'\\',\\'2\\');'"

str.replace('\\', '')
```

use builtin `replace` method, which takes 2 parameters first 1 is which char you want to replace and the 2nd one is which char you want to replace with.

Comment: i watched variables in Pycharm`s Debugger instead using 'print', thank you anyway

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This could work in your case. If the variable is str,

```
str = '(\\'1\\',\\'YoTWsmjxk4M5lqgmzKzF8oI6owoqJBM5mVumQ-0fL01OLS9gU63Gfw**\\',\\'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x94\\xa7\\x2f\\x34\\',\\'\\',\\'2\\');'
```

Replace \\ with nothing everywhere. But then where ever 'x' is there, you lose the \\ preceding the x.

```
str.replace("\\", "");
```

But then as you want it before x, you put back \\ only before x

```
str.replace("x", "\\x");
```

Comment: i watched variables in Pycharm`s Debugger instead using 'print', thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin `replace()` module of `str`.

```
string = "(\\'1\\',\\'YoTWsmjxk4M5lqgmzKzF8oI6owoqJBM5mVumQ-0fL01OLS9gU63Gfw**\\',\\'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x94\\xa7\\x2f\\x34\\',\\'\\',\\'2\\');"

replaced = string.replace("\\'", "'")
print replaced
#Output

"('1','YoTWsmjxk4M5lqgmzKzF8oI6owoqJBM5mVumQ-0fL01OLS9gU63Gfw**','\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x94\\xa7\\x2f\\x34','','2');"
```

Comment: i watched variables in Pycharm`s Debugger instead using 'print', thank you anyway

Comment: @CharlieHuang, you can mark any one answer as the answer which helped you, so the question doesnt remain unanswered.